# equivalence between two definitions of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

the image shows my question. I hope somebody can explain to me how it works.

[image: Question]

Comment: Essentially it's trying to say that the value of the function at $x=n$ is squeezed between two other functions at $x=n$

Comment: @Chopin: What is the first part that you don't understand?

Comment: The sandwich theorem is not my problem. But i don't know why the second part is working. Is there like a proof of the second part ?

Comment: @Chopin `There is a theorem saying this` That's not the squeeze/sandwich theorem. The way you wrote it "$a \le a_n \le a$" is equivalent to $a_n = a \;\;\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is "is the following statement true," then the answer is yes

> **Idea:** If $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in N$ such that for all $n>N$, $a-\epsilon<a_n<a+\epsilon$ then $\lim a_n=a$

This is the definition of a limit, and is true automatically because that's what the symbol $\lim a_n=a$ is defined to mean. It's truth has nothing to do with the sandwich theorem. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for though, because I'm having trouble understanding your wording.

Comment: So is it right, that $ \forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in N $ such for all $ n>N, a-\epsilon<= a_n <= a+\epsilon $ is equivalent to  $ \forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in N $ such for all $ n>N, a-\epsilon< a_n < a+\epsilon $ ?

Comment: @Chopin yeah. Because $\epsilon$ can't equal zero, the equal-to aspect doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Now i understand.